# Converting from Cartesian to polar

Tags: integration

How do we prove that

$$dx dy = r dr d\theta$$

I know the proofs using the Jacobian and Area of Sector. Is there any other way?

Comment: Are you unhappy with those proofs in any way? What are you looking for in a new proof?

Comment: Yes not so intersting ones...but is there any other new proof... more interpretable..more clear....algebraic

Comment: Are you familiar with differential forms? This is the most algebraic I could think of. I'll also edit my answer to include another way.

Comment: No differntial forms don't know..pls add some more detail in proof...step 3 is not clear

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit of what you mean by "other" way, but there's a direct computation using differential forms for example:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm dx\wedge \mathrm dy & =\mathrm d(r\cos \varphi)\wedge \mathrm d(r \sin\varphi)\\ &
=\left(\cos \varphi ~\mathrm dr - r\sin\varphi ~\mathrm d\varphi\right)\wedge \left(\sin \varphi~ \mathrm dr + r\cos\varphi~ \mathrm d\varphi\right)\\
& =r\cos^2\varphi~\mathrm dr\wedge \mathrm d\varphi + r\sin^2\varphi~\mathrm dr\wedge \mathrm d\varphi\\
&= r~\mathrm dr\wedge \mathrm d\varphi
\end{aligned}$$
Sorry I used $\varphi$ instead of $\theta$…

EDIT: Think of the polar coordinate transformation as a map to $\mathbb R^3$ given by
$f:(r,\varphi)\mapsto (r\cos\varphi,r\sin\varphi,0)$.
Then the result follows from the fact that $|\partial_r f\times \partial_\varphi f|=r$ using Lagranges identity:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity

EDIT: To explain step 3 in my proof, note that by antisymmetriy of the wedge-product one has $\mathrm dr\wedge \mathrm dr = 0 =\mathrm d\varphi\wedge \mathrm d\varphi$ and $\mathrm d\varphi\wedge\mathrm dr = - \mathrm dr\wedge\mathrm d\varphi$. Otherwise $\wedge$ behaves like a product so you can distribute multiplication over addition and subtraction.